# I need to make a number pyramid, example 1, 121 , 12321, for n lenght

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Example]

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim lengthr As Integer
Dim lengthc As Integer

lengthr = InputBox("Insert length of pyramid")

lenghtc = lenghtr

For r = 1 To lengthr
    For c = 1 To lengthc
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value = "1"
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, c).Value = "1"
    Next
    lengthc = lengthc - 1
Next

End Sub
```

This is what i have for now, but i don't know how to make every second cell be black color.

I don't know how to do that

Comment: You can add a Step in a For loop.

Comment: Record a macro in which you set the cell background to black.  This should give you sufficient hints.

Comment: `Select Case True // Case i Mod 2 // Case Else` would allow a way to tell if you're inputting a number of adding `interior.color = vbBlack`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim lengthr As Integer
    Dim lengthc As Integer
    
    lengthr = InputBox("Insert length of pyramid")
    
    lengthc = lengthr
    
    With Worksheets("Feuil1")
        .Cells.Clear 'delete existing cells
        For r = 1 To 2 * lengthr
            For c = 2 * lengthr - r To 1 Step -1
                If (r & 1) = (c & 1) Then 'same parity
                    .Cells(r, c) = WorksheetFunction.Min(r, c)
                Else
                    .Cells(r, c).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've googled but can't find anything to explain if (r and 1) is supposed to test if something is uneven or not but I tested with several numbers and can't figure out what exactly it does. (20 And 4) gives 4 but (12 And 3) gives 0, as well as (9 And 2) but (9 And 3) gives 1. It's not the smallest number, it's not Mod(), not division.

Comment: Yes indeed I wanted to write (r & 1) so see if it is odd or even. Will give 1 if r is odd, 0 instead. Thanks for noticing it